# Create a dictionary of dataframe using chunks

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, chunks

I have a dataframe `df` of the type

```
        permno       date time_avail_m  ...  OperProfRD_q  _merge       ret
100000   11167 1989-01-31       1989m1  ...           NaN    both -0.170732
100001   11167 1989-02-28       1989m2  ...           NaN    both -0.088235
100002   11167 1989-03-31       1989m3  ...           NaN    both -0.064516
100003   11167 1989-05-31       1989m5  ...           NaN    both  0.181818
100004   11167 1989-06-30       1989m6  ...           NaN    both  0.179487
```

The result of `df.info()` is

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10000 entries, 10000 to 19999
Columns: 320 entries, permno to ret
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(304), int64(13), object(2)
memory usage: 24.4+ MB
None
```

This is an output obtained by running `df.head` looping over my dataframe `df` in chunks.
I need to create a dictionary of dataframes where the dictionary keys are the values in the column `date` and the keys are dataframes with index `permno` and the remaining columns of `df` as columns. Is there an efficient way to do this? I would like to perform this operation in chunks as `df` is a pretty large database

Comment: can you post the result of `df.info()` in a code block? this could be solved by setting `permno` to be the index, then grouping by `date`

Comment: @RichieV I added the result of df.info()

Comment: do you care about the current index?

Comment: no, it is just the default one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to implement a `groupby` operation for out-of-memory data that is read in chunks.

Sample data

```
import pandas as pd

file = 'C:/users/ricar/downloads/mushrooms.csv' # downloaded from kaggle

# df = pd.read_csv(file, nrows=2)
# df.info()
# Data columns (total 23 columns):
 # #   Column                    Non-Null Count  Dtype
# ---  ------                    --------------  -----
 # 0   class                     2 non-null      object
 # 1   cap-shape                 2 non-null      object
 # 2   cap-surface               2 non-null      object
 # 3   cap-color                 2 non-null      object
 # 4   bruises                   2 non-null      object
 # 5   odor                      2 non-null      object
 # 6   gill-attachment           2 non-null      object
 # 7   gill-spacing              2 non-null      object
 # 8   gill-size                 2 non-null      object
 # 9   gill-color                2 non-null      object
 # 10  stalk-shape               2 non-null      object
 # 11  stalk-root                2 non-null      object
 # 12  stalk-surface-above-ring  2 non-null      object
 # 13  stalk-surface-below-ring  2 non-null      object
 # 14  stalk-color-above-ring    2 non-null      object
 # 15  stalk-color-below-ring    2 non-null      object
 # 16  veil-type                 2 non-null      object
 # 17  veil-color                2 non-null      object
 # 18  ring-number               2 non-null      object
 # 19  ring-type                 2 non-null      object
 # 20  spore-print-color         2 non-null      object
 # 21  population                2 non-null      object
 # 22  habitat                   2 non-null      object
# dtypes: object(23)
# memory usage: 496.0+ bytes
```

Build grouper

```
from collections import defaultdict

# pick your pivot columns
idx = 'cap-shape'
grouper = ['cap-surface']

# populate the grouper
groups = defaultdict(list)
for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, usecols=grouper, chunksize=1000):
    chunk = chunk.reset_index().set_index(grouper).squeeze()
    for key, g in chunk.groupby(chunk.index):
        groups[key].extend(g.to_list())
```

Use it to filter data loaded in chunks

```
# load a single sub-dataframe    
def load_subdf(key, **kwargs):
    out = []
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, **kwargs):
        out.append(chunk[chunk[grouper[0]].eq(key)])
    return pd.concat(out).drop(columns=grouper)

df_f = load_subdf('f', index_col=idx, chunksize=1000)
```

Output

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 2320 entries, x to k
Data columns (total 21 columns):
 #   Column                    Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------                    --------------  -----
 0   class                     2320 non-null   object
 1   cap-color                 2320 non-null   object
 2   bruises                   2320 non-null   object
 3   odor                      2320 non-null   object
 4   gill-attachment           2320 non-null   object
 5   gill-spacing              2320 non-null   object
 6   gill-size                 2320 non-null   object
 7   gill-color                2320 non-null   object
 8   stalk-shape               2320 non-null   object
 9   stalk-root                2320 non-null   object
 10  stalk-surface-above-ring  2320 non-null   object
 11  stalk-surface-below-ring  2320 non-null   object
 12  stalk-color-above-ring    2320 non-null   object
 13  stalk-color-below-ring    2320 non-null   object
 14  veil-type                 2320 non-null   object
 15  veil-color                2320 non-null   object
 16  ring-number               2320 non-null   object
 17  ring-type                 2320 non-null   object
 18  spore-print-color         2320 non-null   object
 19  population                2320 non-null   object
 20  habitat                   2320 non-null   object
dtypes: object(21)
memory usage: 398.8+ KB
```

Notice how the index is no longer the default range index and the grouper column is not part of the result.

---

First answer:

Your dataframe is small enough for in-memory reshaping... try the following

```
df = df.set_index('permno') # discard current index
dict_dfs = {date: gdf for date, gdf in df.groupby('date')}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, the database is really large (what I showed above in ```df.info()``` is the result applied only to a chunk of the database). Is there a way to combine everything but performing the various steps in chunks and then put them back together?

Comment: Yes the code does exactly what I want, so it's perfect. The problem is that if I try to load the full df, it takes more than 80% of the memory, and I have 16gb here. That is why I need to proceed in chunks

Comment: Also, I would need not to have the ```date``` column anymore in the dataframes within each dictionary entry

Comment: so you are loading the data in chunks (with read csv?) and  trying to group by date? you do know that will result in larger memory usage? what will you do with that dict once it is populated?

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying to do because I do not see any other solution to be honest. Ones I have a dictionary of the type described, I need to pass it to a class that needs the input to be in that exact form

Comment: I see, but that dictionary would use 80% of the memory, no room for anything else... have you considered incremental algorithms for whatever that other class is doing to the data?

Comment: I see, you are right. Well since this class needs to be run on a very big database, my idea was first to explore its functionalities (e.g. if I get errors and so on) applying to the dataframe in chunks. Once I know it works, then I would consider something else, but to be honest I haven't though about that part yet

Comment: this question can be solved by creating a grouper dictionary that allows filtering chunks of data (load the data in chunks and identify each row to a date, tag it in the grouper, then when you want to call the df for a date you would have to open every chunk and copy the corresponding rows, slow but effective given the dataset)... but I would try to change the code further down the line before resorting to this

Comment: OK! Any hint is well taken. Could you also show how to obtain dictionaries like in the code you mentioned above but without having the data in the dictionary entry, i.e. having it only as a key?

Comment: So it turns out that I can now manage the full dataframe using up to 60% of the memory, hence it should be tractable. No need to perform steps in chunks